# ldap_add: Object class violation (65) when adding posixGroup

Tags: ldap

I try to move some posixGroup-Definitions from one ldap-server to a new one using

`ldapadd -x -v -W -D cn=ldapAdmin,dc=ibk,dc=local -f groups_ldap_20151028.ldif`

This produces the following error:

```
ldap_initialize( <DEFAULT> )
Enter LDAP Password: 
add objectClass:
        posixGroup
        sambaGroupMapping
add cn:
        users
add displayName:
        users
add sambaGroupType:
        2
add sambaSID:
        S-1-5-21-4027309494-1722177077-478768286-513
add gidNumber:
        100
adding new entry "cn=users,ou=groups,dc=ibk,dc=local"
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
        additional info: no structural object class provided
```

I do not understand what happens here, so please give me a hint. As i found posixGroup' is a structural object, sambaGroupMapping not. Adding 'top' as objectClass did not help. All necessary attributes are set and the old setting worked. Importing users the same way worked also well. Both ldap-version are the same.

EDIT: The primary Problem was the wrong schema which had posixGroup an as structural class. The modern uses the configuration in the description below. The rest was a mess of duplicate names and whitespace in the ldif-file. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding group or groupOfName or groupofUniqueName (depends on LDAP implementation) as an added objectClass. posixGroup is typically an Auxiliary Group

```
'posixGroup' SUP top AUXILIARY DESC 'Abstraction of a group of accounts' MUST gidNumber MAY ( authPassword $ userPassword $ memberUid $ description ) X-ORIGIN 'draft-howard-rfc2307bis' )
```

Comment: Thank you! This took me to the next step. I have looked into the nis.schema, where posixGroup is STRUCTURAL.

Comment: Now there is an invalid syntax (21) error. I think this belongs to the now missing member attribute. Which ist the best way to handle this? Adding all members twice seem not to be a very good solution.

Comment: 'add objectClass:
        groupOfNames 
        posixGroup
        sambaGroupMapping
add cn:
        users
add displayName:
        users
add sambaGroupType:
        2
add sambaSID:
        S-1-5-21-4027309494-1722177077-478768286-513
add gidNumber:
        100
add member:
        cn=useher,ou=users,dc=ibk,dc=local
adding new entry "cn=users,ou=groups,dc=ibk,dc=local"
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
        additional info: objectClass: value #0 invalid per syntax'   Adding one member does not work.